# Routes from the Towns

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are 4 different rods between town A and Town B, 3 different roads between B and C, and 2 different roads between A and C.

**Question:**

**How many different routes are there from A to C and back, which do not use any road twice?**

Here routes and road are two different concepts?
Routes means total path from the A to C and back.
Road between two Town

Correct?

Total routes from the A to B = 4*3 + 2 = 14

Total routes from the A to B and back = 14 * 14 = 196

but can not find the answer to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straightforward though slightly tedious way is to break into cases: (i) out and back through B; (ii) direct out and back; (iii) out through B, back direct; (iv) out direct, back through B.

(i) This may be the hardest one. There are $4$ ways to get to B, and for each choice there are $3$ ways to get to C. Now there are $2$ ways to get back to B, and $3$ ways to get to A. Multiply. We get $(4)(3)(2)(3)$.

(ii) This one is easy, $2$ ways.

(iii) and (iv) Same count for each. It's your turn.

Finally, add up.

Comment: ii) A to C and C to A: 2*1 = 2

Comment: iii) A-B-C and C-A: 4*3 *2 = 24 ??

Comment: Yes, (ii) and (iii) are right.

Comment: iv) 2*3*4 = 24 ??

Comment: Total is 122. Got now

Comment: The answer $122$ is right.  I imagine that now you have the idea fully under control, so don't need confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

That problem is an example of permutation. The formula for permutation is P(n,r); where n is the objects which will be arranged r at a time.

From town A to B, there are 4 roads. From B to C there are 3 roads.

If one go from town A to C, there would be only 2 possible roads from B to C and 3 for A to B.

P(n,r)
=P(3,2)
=3•2      cause there are 2 positions to be filled and the factorial of 3 is 3,2,1 but 3 and 2 are only taken because there are only 2 positions.
=6 ways